# XSL | Transformation for Self Closing tag

Tags: xml, xslt, sql-loader

I am having XML file in which i can receive data in below 4 formats . And using the XSL transformation i am creating infile for SQL LOADER .

```
1)  <gmt:name>OTC<gmt:name/>

2) <gmt:name><gmt:name/>

3) <gmt:name/>

4) Tag not present
```

XSL transformation Code i am using to convert

```
<NAME>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="gmt:name">
        <xsl:value-of select="gmt:name"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</NAME>
```

However with this code 1,2,4 format is getting resolved correctly but for 3rd my code is not working

Results

```
1) <NAME>OTC</NAME>
2) <NAME/>
3) <NAME/>
4) <NAME>NULL</NAME>
```

Hence 3) will not work SQL LOADER and will get failed with error Initial enclosure character not found

please suggest

Comment: I do not see how 3) could be produced with the XSLT you've shown.

Comment: An XSLT processor looks at the source tree produced by the XML parser. In this tree, there is no difference between `<name></name>` and `<name/>`. Both will produce the same result - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHg. If you're seeing something else, you are probably using a non-coforming processor/parser.

Comment: @GSerg , Updated the results

Comment: @michael.hor257k , Yes i am seeing the same results , However SQL Loader need both open and close tag in order to read the record . But since we are getting only closing tag , the SQL Loader is getting failed

Comment: @sharanjain What is the SQL Loader you are talking about and how do you use it?

Comment: You say you are getting the same result, but you're showing a different result for case #2. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Its a control file use to load XML data to oracle . `LOAD DATA
infile 'XML_out.xml' "str '</ROWSET>'"
             APPEND
            INTO TABLE SHM.REF_NAME
            TRAILING NULLCOLS
           (
dummy filler char(1000) terminated by "<ROWSET>",
NAME char(1000) enclosed by "<NAME>" and "</NAME>"
)`

Comment: @michael.hor257k , updated the results

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is perfectly good XML (`<A></A>` and `<A/>` are both perfectly acceptable ways to write an empty element and any decent XML application will treat them as 100% equivalent).

I think you may have misdiagnosed the problem. You haven't made it entirely clear what the symptoms are.

I suspect that your examples (1) and (2) are typos and the closing tag `<A/>` should read `</A>`.

Answer (score 0):

As i workaround by XSTL write output as html

```
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

Code : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHg/2